# What to do with incomprehensible questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many question on WPSE are incomprehensible as poor translation to English has happened. Sometimes you can get the gist of the question but other times the question is so poorly written that no sense can be made of it.

I would normally flag/vote close the question as `not a real question`. But the description of this flag doesn't say anything about the comprehension of the question.

If I am right in flagging the question as `not a real question` then can we change the description to:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   `incomprehensible`, ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or 
>   rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: I do likewise. I infer *incomprehensible* as being within the *penumbra* of "*ambiguous, vague, incomplete...and cannot reasonably be answered in its current form*". But explicitly adding "incomprehensible" to the description would be a reasonable addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "not a real question" is suitable, even without "incomprehensible" in the description.